# How to setup Cordova 9.0.0 on linux pc?

Tags: java, android, linux, cordova

Please let me know how to install Cordova 9.0.0 on Linux PC.

I have completed the setup by using below link:
https://evothings.com/doc/build/cordova-install-linux.html#InstallAndroidSDKTools

I setup the environment variable as below in ~/.bashrc file using nano ~/.bashrc command:

```
JAVA_HOME=/home/user5/java/jdk-12.1.0
PATH=$PATH:/home/user5/java/jdk-12.0.1/bin
export JAVA_HOME

ANT_HOME=/home/user5/ant/apache-ant-1.9.14
PATH=$PATH:/home/user5/ant/apache-ant-1.9.14/bin
export ANT_HOME

PATH=$PATH:/home/user5/android-sdk-linux/android-studio //Here in android SDK I haven't received the package platform-tools folder.
PATH=$PATH:/home/user5/android-sdk-linux/tools

PATH=$PATH:home/user5/gradle/gradle-5.5/bin

export PATH
```

Still I am getting following error.

`user5@user5-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~/Documents/Projects/cordovaApp$ cordova build android`

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/user5/android-sdk-linux (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 12.0.1
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
user5@user5-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~/Documents/Projects/cordovaApp$

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: From the [original docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html) looks like JVM 8 is needed, you installed JVM 12, and it doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your comment. After updating JVM 8 it's working fine.